# What does // mean in Mathematica?

Tags: syntax, operators, wolfram-mathematica

Examples:

- In

  ```
  CT = Table[Prepend[10^4*x[range2] /.
       NDSolve[{...series of equations here...}, {t, range1, range2}, 
          MaxSteps -> 10000,
          PrecisionGoal -> 11], delay], 
          {delay, delaymin, delaymax, 0.1}]; // Timing
  ```

what does it mean this `// Timing` after the semicolon?

- In

  ```
  Dρ = -I*((H0 + V).ρ - ρ.(H0 + V)) - Γ*ρ // Simplify;
  ```

And this `// Simplify` here?

I can't find this explanation anywhere!

Thanks in advance,
Thiago

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please [see this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if you have questions about the site.

Comment: Trick to see full form of stuff is `FullForm[Hold[stuff]]` . Also try  `TreeForm[Hold[stuff]]`

Answer (score 3):

This is Mathematica's [postfix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Postfix.html) notation. 
Basically x//f is the same as f[x]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `argument // function` is postfix function application.

Useful about it is that it has a different, lower binding power relative to prefix application (`f @ x`).

In fact it is lower than most other things (exceptions include `CompoundExpression` `;` and `Set` `=`), and therefore it can often be considered as "apply to everything before this."

Answer (score 3):

You say: "I can't find this explanation anywhere!". I assume this means you are not aware of the documentation center that's right under your fingertips whenever you're using Mathematica.

All you have to do is to place your cursor on the `//` and press F1 and you'll get some sort of explanation, or a list with relevant (hopefully) matches. In this case the `PostFix` page, which is not extremely helpful. However, it has some links at the bottom (assuming you have versions 6, 7 or 8) that provide more insight, among which a link to the syntax overview page (click the Mathematica syntax link, or enter "guide/Syntax" in the search box).

Comment: I am aware of the documentation available online on Mathematica's website. I always work with it open. But, as you said, the Postfix page is not helpful or straightforward whatsoever. My Mathematica version is 6, but we already ordered the license for the newest version at work. Must be available soon here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`expr // f` is essentially equivalent to `f[expr]`. Sometimes, it's called postfix notation. I read `expr // f` as "pass the expression `expr` to the function `f`".

Answer (score 2):

```
a // f
```

is, I believe, the same thing as

```
f[a]
```

(which incidentally, any sane mathematician I know would write as

```
f(a)
```

just as it is done in most computer languages.)

Comment: f(a) as a mathematical notation is pretty ambiguous. Yes, it could mean the function f of x but it could also mean f times the expression a between parenthesis.

Comment: True. (Unless you have proper typesetting and a trained eye to see the difference in spacing between the two, of course.) But `f[a]` is neither a standard math notation nor better in this regard, since many people (especially, but not only, those also using programming languages) will read it as an index. I've seen papers where subscripting and brackets have been used interchangeably, depending on the complexity of the subscript.

Comment: If you really must have it that way, you can have it displayed with parenthesis if you use TraditionalForm.

Comment: BTW _sane mathematician_ is an oxymoron

Comment: @Sjoerd: I know. If I was a Mathematica user, I'd probably also know how to make it accept usual, er, “traditional” input form. But I don't really care.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, `//` is the postfix notation and `expr//f` means `f[expr]` in mathematica and `f(expr)` in math.

Although there might be more subtleties involved, my usage of `//` has often been in cases where I've started writing out an expression and then realized I wanted to operate a function on it. So instead of moving the cursor all the way back to type `f@expr` or `f[expr]`, I can simply finish typing what I had in mind, and use `expr//f`.

Example:

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,Pi}]
%//Export["test.pdf",#]&
```

The graphics is passed to the export function and is saved as `test.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

As your question has already got very good answers, I want to add just a clarification on usage.

The three expressions

```
Sin[x]
Sin@x
x // Sin
```

Are equivalent.

Although, to my knowledge, the last two can't be used with functions with more than one argument. So

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

Can't be invoked in prefix or postfix notation without tricks like

```
Sin[x] // Plot[#, {x, 0, Pi}] &
```

or

```
Plot[#, {x, 0, Pi}] &@Sin[x]
```

The prefix notation is usually seen when using simple functions like `Sin@x` or `Sort@list`, while most uses of the postfix involve a reasoning like "and now do whatever with this thing I got", for example

```
(Sin@x+ ...) // Timing
```

where you decided what to calculate, and then you also want it timed.

One more note:

Really there is much more under the scenes, as the priority of each of these functional constructs is different, but I think that is a much deeper subject and you have to experiment a little before going for subtleties.

Comment: As an aside, I tend to use the postfix form extensively, where I view each subsequent function as a transformation of the data produced by the prior result. This can lead to inefficient code, at times, and sometimes requires significant convolutions to do (e.g. `f[x] // g /@ #&` is not exactly straightforward). But, I found it helps me think through the the individual steps I need to perform, although it is does require some thinking (and contortions) when multiple execution paths are required to solve the problem.